# How to make a VPS with multiple IPs to proxy with more than 1 IP?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, vps, socks, dante

I have a Ubuntu VPS with four different public IP addresses.

I want to use this VPS as a socks5 proxy in firefox browser, curl and other software with the possibility to use all public IPs of that machine using a socks5 proxy like Dante or any other.

What do you think that it is the best approach to make this config? Maybe a github script, using net rules on VPS?

I need to have four different socks5 proxies with different IPs.

VPS is running Ubuntu Linux, and proxy software is Dante, or if someone knows other easiest way to make that I like. I found this https://github.com/lozy/danted  maybe it can help.

Comment: I feel the question is really about how to bind each proxy instance to its own outgoing IP? Then it depends on what exactly software you are end up using, and that's likely covered in the manual. The second problem would be how to run several instances. That, again, depends on how to set up and it is covered in the software manual and the systemd trickery. Please, elaborate question more, because currently it is quite vague.

Comment: Yes, bind iP to interface, or maybe, rotate that 4 Ips using Dante soft. So if i use that proxy in Firefox, the ip iss not always the same. I'd like to have 4 firefox profiles with 4 diferents IPs, but if that is not posible, rotating can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can run as many socks proxies as you want, each on a separate VPS instance, then load balance your outbound browser connections with NGINX, DNS, or some other solution.

If you insist to have a single server, then you will have to run separate instances of your VPS. That will likely require some coding to get it to work the way you want, but you would still have the problem of load balancing your browser sessions across VPS instances.

Comment: i wont would use a prixy i would use vpn since some programs dont support proxy and you wont need to apply it everytime you may need to use it to the cmd you are trying

Comment: I unsderstan and i know how to set up VPN, but i want use socks5 proxy. And using proxychains i think i can use any program with socks5 proxie.

Comment: @mtv969 i need use only 1 VPS...you say run different instances of Danted? I only want to  use 4 firefox profiles on my pc, and use the socks5 proxy server diferent with every profile, if that is no posible,  maybe rotate the ips on server.